# SVG Symbol not showing on FireFox

Tags: svg

Simple code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 983.4 983.4">
     <symbol id="sym01" viewBox="0 0 150 110">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="8" stroke="red" fill="red"/>
      <circle cx="90" cy="60" r="40" stroke-width="8" stroke="green" fill="white"/>
    </symbol> 

     <use href="#sym01" x="100" y="100" width="100" height="50"/>
</svg>
```

If Chrome the icon is shown perfectly.

In Firefox (latest version) nothing is shown.

Why is that?

Comment: and the namespace declaration for `xlink` is wrong in the `<svg>` tag.

Comment: @omriman12 I'm using firefox and the snippet right here in the question works fine. (before you edited anyway; you took away the "xlink:".)

Comment: yup its working, thx guys, I have a prob now with rendering it with react :S

Answer (score 2):

Firefox only supports xlink:href and not just href.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 983.4 983.4">
     <symbol id="sym01" viewBox="0 0 150 110">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke-width="8" stroke="red" fill="red"/>
      <circle cx="90" cy="60" r="40" stroke-width="8" stroke="green" fill="white"/>
    </symbol> 

     <use xlink:href="#sym01" x="100" y="100" width="100" height="50"/>
</svg>
```